# Jacobian of iterated map proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a diffeomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and I denote by $\Phi^k$ the iteration of such map for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ multiple times with $\Phi^0 = \text{Identity}$, and denote the Jacobian as $J_\Phi(x)$ and the absolute determinant of it as $\mathbf{J}_{\Phi}(x)$. I am told that for an fixed $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for any $j\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$
\mathbf{J}_{\Phi^{-j}}(\Phi^k(x)) = \frac{\mathbf{J}_{\Phi^{k-j}}(x)}{\mathbf{J}_{\Phi^k}(x)}
$$
or, more explicitly
$$
\left|\det J_{\Phi^{-j}}(\Phi^k(x))\right| = \frac{\left|\det J_{\Phi^{k-j}}(x)\right|}{\left|\det J_{\Phi^k}(x)\right|}.
$$

## My working

I tried to prove this using the identity $J_{\Phi^{-1}} = J_{\Phi}^{-1}$ but that lead me nowhere. I thought it might have to do with the Jacobian of a composition that is $J_{g\circ f}(x) = J_g(f(x))J_f(x)$ but again that lead me nowhere.

## Solution

Indeed it is an application of the chain rule $J_{g\circ f}(x) = J_g(f(x))J_f(x)$. Simply recognise that our term is fundamentally $J_g(f(x))$ and so we just consider its multiplication with $J_f(x)$. In our case this is
$$
J_{\Phi^{-j}}(\Phi^k(x)) J_{\Phi^k}(x) = J_{\Phi^{-j}\circ \Phi^k}(x) = J_{\Phi^{k-j}}(x)
$$
automatically, requiring that $J_{\Phi^k}(x) > 0$ we get
$$
J_{\Phi^{-j}}(\Phi^k(x)) = \frac{J_{\Phi^{k-j}}(x)}{J_{\Phi^k}(x)}
$$